# Show that $\det(A_n) = n + 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that for the following matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
     2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
     1 & 2 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     0  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
     \vdots  & \ddots& \ddots & 2 & 1 \\
     0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 2    
     \end{pmatrix}\in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{Q})$$

$\det(A_n) = n + 1$ is true.

I'm not able to prove it, I tried maybe showing that by using Laplace the determinant won't change. Is it easier to prove this using induction?

Help appreciated!

Comment: This seems like a great opportunity to use induction and cofactor expansion

Comment: @bburGsamohT: Exactly!

Comment: The problem is that I cant write $A_ {n+1}$ = $A_n$ + Rest, since $A_{n+1}$ has other dimensions than $A_n$ if you know what I mean

Comment: @user305938 I just uploaded an answer below.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's a nice and elegant proof!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by induction: base cases $n=1,2$ may be checked by hand easily. Let's assume it holds for the $n\times n$ version of the matrix $A_n$. Now examine $A_{n+1}$. We will cofactor expand on the first row to get 
$$
\det(A_{n+1})=2\det (A_n)-\det (B_n),
$$
where $B_n$ is the matrix 
$$
B_n=\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots &\cdots& 0 \\
     0 & 2 & 1 & \ddots &\ddots& \vdots \\
     0  & 1 & 2 & \ddots & \ddots&\vdots \\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
     \vdots  &\ddots& \ddots& \ddots & 2 & 1 \\
     0 & \cdots &\cdots& 0 & 1 & 2    
     \end{pmatrix}
$$
Sorry for the bad formatting of $B_n$, but hopefully you get the idea. Anyways, now cofactor expand on the first *column* of $B_n$ to get $\det(B_n)=\det(A_{n-1})$. So we have 
$$
\det(A_{n+1})=2\det(A_n)-\det(A_{n-1})=2n-(n-1)=n+1
$$
by our induction hypothesis

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use a recursive proof: develop determinant at the first column: $det(A_{n+1})=2det(A_n)-det(A_{n-1})$